# C++ Printing an object in multiple ways

Tags: c++, iostream

If I take a simple date object:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
    int mo, da, yr;
public:
    Date(int m, int d, int y)
    {
        mo = m; da = d; yr = y;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Date dt(5, 6, 92);
    cout << dt;
}
```

and I wish to have the option to print it in a way people from the UK will understand i.e.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    os << dt.da << '/' << dt.mo << '/' << dt.yr;
    return os;
}
```

How is the best way to allow users of the class to choose between 2 (or more) print options?

I was thinking of something similar to returning two separate classes from two methods of the date class that each have their operator<< overloaded in the 2 different ways. But Is there a better way?

code from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

Comment: Does `strftime` exist on your system?

Comment: Check the culture info for the OS and use that in the stream operator. Alternatively, have a static member to select format?

Comment: Should have a look at locale: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement a [manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/).

I am sure there is support in C++ for implementing your own. For inspiration, have a look at how, say, `std::showbase`/`std::noshowbase` is implemented in your environment. You'd need to implement ukdate/noukdate .

Edit: `showbase` is indeed too narrow example for this - we'd need to allocate per-stream word using `std::ios_base::xalloc`.

Comment: `showbase`/`noshowbase` work by setting/unsetting a format flag for the stream. One that is explicity designed for that purpose. What flag would you set for `ukdate`/`noukdate`?

Comment: You'd have to use std::ios_base::xalloc

Answer (score 9):

A *culture-dependent* stream formatting (such as for dates, monetary) should base on [`std::locale`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/locale) settings of a given stream:

```
#include <locale>
#include <ostream>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Date& dt)
{
    std::time_base::dateorder d = std::use_facet<std::time_get<char>>(os.getloc())
                                      .date_order();

    if (d == std::time_base::dmy)
    {
        // Selected format is day / month / year
        os << dt.da << '/' << dt.mo << '/' << dt.yr;
    }
    else if (d == std::time_base::mdy)
    {
        // Selected format is month / day / year
        os << dt.mo << '/' << dt.da << '/' << dt.yr;
    }
    else
    {
        // Default format is year . month . day
        os << dt.yr << '.' << dt.mo << '.' << dt.da;
    }

    return os;
}
```

This allows users of your class to select between different formats (assuming the locale are supported), so that the output is adjusted for a given culture:

```
Date d{ 9, 8, 2014 };

std::cout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
std::cout << d << std::endl;

std::cout.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.utf8"));
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c6b650797ec54fe)

Comment: May be better to use `imbue`/`getloc` ?

Comment: @Arkadiy I am using imbue/getloc